# Javascript Ajax page starts responding slow after some time?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, google-maps-markers

I have a JavaScript ajax page, which fires an ajax request (using setInterval function) every 20 seconds and gets response in `JSON` format. In the page; using `JSON` response I'm displaying the markers on Google map (using API v3) and updating them every 20 seconds based on the location received from `ajax` response. I'm displaying an `infoWindow` on click event of marker.

I am using PHP as server side scripting, which generates my ajax response by doing some DB calls.

Everything works fine when I open the page. But slowly the page starts responding slow. I mean when I click on the marker or on related text, page takes a significant time to locate the marker, to load the map and to open the `infoWindow`. And the slowness of page increases as the time passes. If I refresh the page, again everything starts working fine.

The page don't even show a single error at any point of time and I must add that the auto updation of location of markers works fine throughout the life of the page.

I've tried everything which I found on forums. Like, I've moved to `json` response from an `xml(dom)` response. I've tried changing the `XMLHttpRequest` methods, as the GET requests have tendency to auto cache the data. But nothing helped me. I am completely clueless, what is wrong, what I am doing in my code.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
var contentString = "";
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: contentString});
var url = "genAjaxResponse.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>";
var marker;
var gmarkers = new Array();
var icon;

var lastClickedMarker;
var stImgId;

var customIcons = {
  Moving: {
    icon: 'icons/abc.png'
  },
  Idle: {
    icon: 'icons/xyz.png'
  },
  Parked: {
    icon: 'icons/pqr.png'
  },
  Alert: {
    icon: 'icons/wxy.png'
  }
};

function load() {  // to be called on onload event of body
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {           
        zoom: 6,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        scaleControl: true,
        center:new google.maps.LatLng(15.570128,78.957092)
  });


  calldownloadUrl(url,map,infoWindow);

  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
}

function calldownloadUrl(url,map,infoWindow) {
    downloadUrl(url,displayMarker,map,infoWindow);  
}

function displayMarker(data,map,infoWindow) {

    function generateTriggerCallback(object, eventType) {
        return function() {
            google.maps.event.trigger(object, eventType);
        };
    }

var namearr = Array();
    var json = data.responseText;
    var vehicles = eval ("(" + json + ")");

    var i = 0;
    for (var veh in vehicles)
    {
    var tag = vehicles[veh];            
    var veh_no = tag["veh_no"];
        var is_stale = tag["is_stale"];
        var ignition_off = tag["ignition_off"];
        var speed = tag["speed"];
        var lat = tag["lat"];
        var lng = tag["lng"];
        var time = tag["time_stamp"];
        var address = tag["address"];

        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(lat),
            parseFloat(lng));
        var type;                 
        var status;

        stImgId = i+1;
        if(ignition_off == 0 && speed > 3) {
            type = "Moving";
            status = type + "(" + speed + " Kmph)"; 
            document.getElementById("img"+stImgId).src = "icons/greenalert2.png";
        }
        else {
            if(ignition_off == 1) {
                type = "Parked";
                status = type;
                document.getElementById("img"+stImgId).src = "icons/greyalert2.png";
            }
            else {
                type = "Idle";
                status = type;
                document.getElementById("img"+stImgId).src = "icons/yellowalert2.png";
            }
        }
        if(is_stale == 1) {
            type = "Alert";
            status = type;
            document.getElementById("img"+stImgId).src = "icons/redalert2.png";
        }                 

        infoWindow.close();

        var icon = customIcons[type] || {};         
        if(typeof gmarkers[i] != 'undefined') { 
            gmarkers[i].setPosition(point); 
            gmarkers[i].setIcon(icon.icon);
            if(gmarkers[i].id == lastClickedMarker)  {
                if(map.getBounds().contains(gmarkers[i].getPosition()) === false)
                    map.setCenter(gmarkers[i].getPosition());
            }                   
        }
        else
        { 
            gmarkers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({ 
                    id: i,
                    position: point,
                    icon: icon.icon,
                    title: veh_no,
                    map: map
            }); 
        }
        var html = "<span><p><b>"+veh_no +"</b></p> <p>Address: "+address+"<br />Status: "+status+"<br />Time: "+time+"</p></span>";

        namearr[i] = "<span><p><b>"+veh_no +"</b></p> <p>Address: "+address+"<br />Status: "+status+"<br />Time: "+time+"</p></span>";

        // -- bind click event to texts (vehicle nos) -- //
        var textclick = document.getElementById(i);
        textclick.onclick = generateTriggerCallback(gmarkers[i],"click");
        // -- bind click event to markers -- //
        bindinfoWindow(gmarkers[i], map, infoWindow, namearr[i], icon);
        i++;
    }
}

function bindinfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html, icon) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {       
    lastClickedMarker = marker.id;
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    if(map.zoom < 15)
        map.setZoom(15);        
    marker.setIcon(icon.icon);        
    marker.setZIndex(google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX + 1);        
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback, map, infoWindow) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, map, infoWindow, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send();
}

function doNothing() {}

window.setInterval(function() {calldownloadUrl(url,map,infoWindow)},20000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've a similar app and I've also ran into similar behavior.
In my case, I've been updating an array of markers every 30 secs (for each marker: location, icon, content of a listener).

**Firstly**, I have stopped creating a new marker each update, I thought that setting `markers[id].setMap(null);` and creating new one will be OK, that CG will handle this.

**Then** I've changed the code to only update markers position, icon and listener, like this:

```
 this.markers[id].setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
 this.markers[id].setIcon(this.updateFlags(status, id));

 google.maps.event.addListener(this.markers[id], 'mouseover', function () {
     infoWindow.setContent(text);
     infoWindow.open(this.map, this);
 });

 google.maps.event.addListener(this.markers[id], 'click', function () {
     devices.selectDevice(index);
 });
```

This produced much less consumed memory, but still...

**Finally** I've edited code like this:

```
 this.markers[id].setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
 this.markers[id].setIcon(this.updateFlags(status, id));

 google.maps.event.clearListeners(this.markers[id], 'mouseover');
 google.maps.event.clearListeners(this.markers[id], 'click');

 google.maps.event.addListener(this.markers[id], 'mouseover', function () {
     infoWindow.setContent(text);
     infoWindow.open(this.map, this);
 });

 google.maps.event.addListener(this.markers[id], 'click', function () {
     devices.selectDevice(index);
 });
```

I've tested it in **Chrome Developer Tools (F12) -> Profiler** and **Take Heap Snapshot**. And you will see if it grows too fast.

**So in your case it would mean adding this line as the first line of function bindinfoWindow():**

```
google.maps.event.clearListeners(marker, 'click');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It just worked. It was actually growing too fast. But as soon as I started clearing Listeners, before adding a new one, it became constant. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to empty the `gmarkers` array each time you calling that ajax request, or reset the `i` variable before you processing the received data. In this way you are not adding all the new markers to the previous ones, which seems is the bottleneck in your code.

P.S. I didn't test your code. I'm just guessing.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your response.
I guess you didn't notice that I am not adding/appending any new markers in each ajax call. I am creating them only once and after that if they are already defined ( `typeof gmarkers[i] != 'undefined'` ) I am simply changing the position of them ( `gmarkers[i].setPosition(point);` )

and regarding the `var i`.. I am already resetting it to 0 in each ajax call.